# Ansible: multi line over playbook

Tags: yaml, ansible, multiline

I have a question about multi line and Ansible playbook:

I have created a playbook with a line very large, I need to cut this line for better reading. How I can doing it?

```
  - name: 'Create VM Azure :-P '
    shell: if ! grep {{ item }} /tmp/vm_{{ rgName }}; then azure vm create --vm-size {{ groups['item'][vmsize] }} --resource-group {{ rgName }} --name {{ item }} --location {{ location }} --admin-username {{ username }} --ssh-publickey-file {{ sshfile }} --storage-account-name {{ rgName | lower }} --os-type {{ groups['item'][type_os] }} --image-urn {{ image }} --data-disk-size {{ disksize }} --subnet-id {{ subnetid_key }} --nic-names {{ item }}; fi
    with_items: groups['test']
```

I would like to make it as follows way, but I have some errors when execute the playbook

```
      - name: 'Create VM Azure :-P '
        shell: if ! grep {{ item }} /tmp/vm_{{ rgName }}; then 
                azure vm create --vm-size {{ groups['item'][vmsize] }} 
                --resource-group {{ rgName }} --name {{ item }} 
                --location {{ location }} --admin-username {{ username }} 
                --ssh-publickey-file {{ sshfile }} --storage-account-name {{ rgName | lower }} 
                --os-type {{ groups['item'][type_os] }} --image-urn {{ image }} 
                --data-disk-size {{ disksize }} --subnet-id {{ subnetid_key }} 
                --nic-names {{ item }}; fi
        with_items: groups['test']
```

The error:

ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.

The error appears to have been in '/home/pvillarruel/docker/azure-ansible/data/playbook.yml': line 79, column 1, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
shell: if ! grep {{ item }} /tmp/vm_{{ rgName }}; then azure vm create --vm-size
   {{ groups['item'][vmsize] }} --resource-group {{ rgName }} --name {{ item }}
```

^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes.  Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use a YAML block scalar, they were designed exactly for this kind of thing:

```
  shell: >
    if ! grep {{ item }} /tmp/vm_{{ rgName }}; then 
    azure vm create --vm-size {{ groups['item'][vmsize] }} 
    --resource-group {{ rgName }} --name {{ item }} 
    --location {{ location }} --admin-username {{ username }} 
    --ssh-publickey-file {{ sshfile }}
    --storage-account-name {{ rgName | lower }} 
    --os-type {{ groups['item'][type_os] }} --image-urn {{ image }} 
    --data-disk-size {{ disksize }} --subnet-id {{ subnetid_key }} 
    --nic-names {{ item }}; fi
```

The `>` indicates that the following block is a scalar and lines should be folded, i.e. a newline character will be converted into a single space. You also do not need to worry about special characters, everything will be taken literally in a folded block scalar.